# How to use split function in perl to do the work of awk

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I am writing a script in perl and I want to avoid using external commands as awk, tr , etc as much as possible.
This is the command I am running from inside the script , using backticks:

```
my @arr = `$cmd | tr " " "\n" | xargs -n1 host | awk '{print $4}'`
```

And this is the output with out `awk '{print 4$}` :

```
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.59
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.34
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.56
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.67
```

This is the output with `awk '{print 4$}`:

```
10.90.207.59
10.90.207.34
10.90.207.56
10.90.207.67
```

I want each IP to be in a separated cell in the array.
How can I use perl functions (maybe split or map) currectrly instead of using awk and tr?

Comment: Input and desired output?

Comment: are the addresses always IPv4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trivially. By default `split` works just like `awk`. So:

```
my @arr = split;
print $arr[3]; #note - arrays start at zero.
```

However, perl generally also works line by line on a filehandle, and a `split` gets you stuff you don't want.

You can either:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
   my ($ip) = (split)[3];
   print $ip, "\n";
   #or push it. 
}

__DATA__
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.59
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.34
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.56
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.67
```

But if you're looking for a single thingummy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @ips = map { (split)[3] } <DATA>;

print Dumper \@ips;


__DATA__
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.59
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.34
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.56
$fileserver has address 10.90.207.67
```

We read `<DATA>` in a list context, so it returns the whole thing - one element at a time to map.

And then in the `map` we split each, and grab element `3` (`$4` in awk terms).

Comment: That is great , thank you! , is there any thing I can do regarding the 'tr' command?

Comment: Yes. But I wouldn't because what _that_ bit is doing is running multiple commands using `xargs` and I'd just run the commands one at a time in `perl` instead.

Answer (score 5):

For similar use perl one liner

```
perl -nae 'print "$F[3]\n"' input.txt
```

`-n` make the loop for a file

`-a` autosplit mode. By default split with space. The output stored into the `@F`. So I use third index to print the ip address. In perl index start with 0

Comment: Thanks nice way as well!

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the field that you want is the last column, you can use an index that counts backward from the end:

```
my $ip = (split)[-1];
```

In the one-liner case, using the `-a` switch makes Perl split the line into the `@F` array (the `-n` wraps `while(<>){...}` around the argument to `-e` and the `-l` adds a newline to each `print` (see [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html))):

```
perl -anle 'print $F[-1]'
```

However, since you're not stuck with awk, you don't have to do it that way. You can probably do most of that in Perl without the pipeline. Here's what you started with:

```
my @arr = `$cmd | tr " " "\n" | xargs -n1 host | awk '{print $4}'`
```

It looks like `$cmd` generates a bunch of host names in a single line. You turn spaces into newlines with the `tr`, then run `host` on each of lines. For each `host` output, you grab the address.

You could do that in a single Perl program:

```
 use v5.24;

 use Socket;        # core module
 use Net::hostent;  # core module

 my $cmd = ...;
 foreach my $host ( `$cmd` ) {
      chomp( $host );
      my @addresses = 
          map { inet_ntoa($_) } 
          gethostbyname($host)->addr_list->@*;
      say join "\n", @addresses;
     }
```

With the backticks in a list context, Perl breaks the output of the command into lines for you. The core modules [Socket](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Socket) and [Net::hostent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Net::hostent) come with Perl.

I've used v5.24 for its very nice [postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) feature, `->@*`, that turns the array reference from `addr_list` into a regular list that `map` can use.

You need to be careful about whatever you put in `$cmd`. I talk about that at length in the "Security" chapter of [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org). You can also find some stuff in the [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the `inet_aton` and `inet_ntoa` from the [`Socket`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Socket) module, you can very simply do the entire thing in Perl, with the exception of `$cmd` because you don't tell us what that is

It looks like your `$cmd` returns one or more lines of host names, separated by spaces, so I've used an `echo` command to emulate it here. I've also used `Data::Dump` just to reveal the final contents of `@addresses`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Socket;

my $cmd = 'echo www.amazon.co.uk www.perl.com www.stackoverflow.com';

my $cmd_output = `$cmd`;
my @addresses = map { name_to_ip($_) } split ' ', $cmd_output;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@addresses;

sub name_to_ip {

    my ($name) = @_;
    my $add32 = inet_aton($name) or die qq{Unable to convert host name "$name": $!\n};

    inet_ntoa($add32);
}
```

#### output

```
["54.239.36.155", "207.171.7.72", "151.101.193.69"]
```

Answer (score 0):

perl oneliners to the rescue - list my taxi receipts, sort by the 4th col, with `_` token delim:

```
    ls -1 | sort -t'_' -k 4| grep -i taxi
    00016,70_2021-12-04_OL_2021-12-04_id-10_LahiTaxi-Oy_TaxiKuljetus.jpg
    00125,10_2021-12-04_OL_2021-12-04_id-11_Tom-Lindroos_Taxipalvelut.jpg
```

seem them as a table (for each row in the console, grab into the `@a` array ( this could be even shorter ... ) , than refer to each element of the array by it's index:

```
ls -1 | sort -t'_' -k 4|perl -ne 'chomp($_);@a=split/_/;print "$a[4]\t$a[3]\t$a[2]\t$a[1]\t$a[5]\t$a[6]\t$a[0]\n"' | grep -i taxi

    id-10   2021-12-04      OL      2021-12-04      LahiTaxi-Oy     TaxiKuljetus.jpg        00016,70
    id-11   2021-12-04      OL      2021-12-04      Tom-Lindroos    Taxipalvelut.jpg        00125,10
```

put them into a csv file, to import into xls, google sheet:

```
  ls -1 | sort -t'_' -k 4|perl -ne 'chomp($_);@a=split/_/;print "$a[4];$a[3];$a[2];$a[1];$a[5];$a[6];$a[0]\n"' > ../lst.csv
```